# java hibernate question

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a object (parent object) which has a child object and that child object has another child object in it.

I am using Hibernate and when i fetch the parent object the child object is lazily loaded.

But the child objects child object is Eagerly loaded.

But when i say `patient.getChildObject().getChildObject()` it is null.

Can someone explain me how i can fetch the child objects,child object while fetching the parent object?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code and mapping?

Answer (score 0):

A messy, and **not recommended** approach, is to store the id of the child-child-object in the child-object. You can then to the following:

```
    ChildChild cc = (ChildChild) 
        session.load(ChildChild.class, Parent.Child.getChildId());
```

Not pretty, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

add @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) or @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) or @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) or @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  as your need for every child object reference.